# Remove space or replace with underscore of auto generated ID tags

Tags: php, html, mysql, navigation

Completely revising my question.

I am using this code to generate an id tag:

```
$items.="<h3 id='$heading_old' class='cateory_h' style='width: 100%; display: flow-root; margin: 10px 10px; font-weight: 600; color: #bcd63a;'> $heading_old</a></h3>";
```

Which produces this html:

```
<h3 id='Craft Cocktails' class='cateory_h' style='width: 100%; display: flow-root; margin: 10px 10px; font-weight: 600; color: #bcd63a;'> Craft Cocktails</a></h3><div class="beers">
```

I cant have a space in the id. I need to either remove it on replace it with an underscore.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

This did not work:

```
document.getElementById("Lighter Beers").id = "Lighter_Beers";
```

Thanks to Nico Bleiler for pointing out my original code errors!

Comment: Since I know the categories in advance, is there a way to pre-assign them id's or anchors?

Comment: Do NOT use spaces in the href value

Comment: I tried that and instead of working it sends me to the home page?

Comment: If you click a link that only hast a fragment like #test it only updates that and does not redirect you somewhere else

Comment: I understand that. Is there a way to convert id='$heading_old' to insert the _ in to the result?

Comment: Can you give an example of how it looks like after php filled the data

Comment: Check my answer and use `urlencode` on both ends and it should work

Comment: Will definitely try that again. YOu guidence has been much appreciated. I just need to figure out how to do that lol

Comment: Got it working to put + where the space is. Now I just need to get the link to actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the anchor to work properly the fragment in url has to be identical to the id of the element.

```
<a href="#test">Go to Test</a>
```

If you click it it will update the URI fragment and scroll to the element on the page that has the id

```
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

Use the method `urlencode ( string $str ) : string` on your variable like

```
urlencode($heading_old)
```

and encode the a tags yourself to match them

I inspected your a tags.

It seems like you used the wrong apostrophe.

The Browser updated your example and corrected it

`<a href="“#Craft_Cocktails”">Craft Cocktails</a>`

You mixed `“` and `"`

```
<ul class="nav2">
    <li><a href="#Craft_Cocktails">Craft Cocktails</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Darker_Beers">Darker Beers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Lighter_Beers">Lighter Beers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Hoppy_Beers">Hoppy Beers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Wild_and_Sour">Wild and Sour</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Wine_and_Cider">Wine and Cider</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is the issue. I am trying to assign an id that matches the result of $heading_old, and the way I am doing it returns the fragmented id.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I made the change and it is still just sending me to the home page. So it has to be the way I am assigning the id is incorrect.

Comment: Give an example of your header with the id in it, not the templated version

Comment: I am not understanding your suggestion or question? Sorry

Comment: I want to know the value of $heading_old, i would like to know what the final html is.
Like `<div id="test">Test</div>`

Comment: I just updated my original question with the final html. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I have been trying to figure out urlencode ( string $str ) : string for hours now lol

Comment: you call the function `urlencode($string)`, and it returns the specified string encoded url safe

Comment: I have this that encodes them: $segment2 = 'Darker Beers';
$path2 = urlencode($segment2);
$segment3 = 'Lighter Beers';
$path3 = urlencode($segment3);      This creates the menu links:  
  <li><a href="#<?php echo $path2 ?>">Darker Beers</a></li>
  <li><a href="#<?php echo $path3 ?>">Lighter Beers</a></li>    Which comes back with <a href="“#Darker+Beers" target="_blank">Darker Beers</a>